# How can Apache POI use formulas in streaming mode?

Tags: java, apache-poi, formulas

I am using Apache POI 3.17 (current). When I use HSSFCell.setFormula() to insert a formula like "A1+17" it works. When I do the same in streaming mode, using SXSSFCell.setFormula() the formula appears (with a leading "=") in the input line but the displayed result in the cell is always 0.

I tried with the cell types NUMERIC and FORMULA. Here is my minimal not working example:

```
 final SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(); 
 final SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Test-S");
 final SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

 final SXSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
 cell1.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
 cell1.setCellValue(124);

 final SXSSFCell formulaCell1 = row.createCell(1);
 formulaCell1.setCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
 formulaCell1.setCellFormula("A1 + 17");

 final SXSSFCell formulaCell2 = row.createCell(2);
 formulaCell2.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
 formulaCell2.setCellFormula("A1+18");

 FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test-s.xlsx");
 wb.write(os);
 wb.close();
 os.close();
```

The three cells display as 124/0/0, although in the input line the formulae are displayed correctly.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me with Excel 2016, I get the correct results in the cells when I open the sample file. Probably older versions of Excel handle this slightly differently, please try to force evaluation of formulas with the following two things

```
// evaluate all formulas and store cached results
wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
// suggest to Excel to recalculate the formulas itself as well
sheet.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```

Hopefully one of those two will make it work for you as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! evaluateAll() did the trick. But I am going to keep both of the proposed statements.

Comment: A few additional remarks: In some cases evaluateAll() may throw an exception, saying that a row has already been flushed. In this case evaluateFormulaCellEnum(cell) can be used.

Answer (score 3):

The answers does not answer the question why this problem with OpenOffice/Libreoffice only occurs if `SXSSFCell` is used as a formula cell. When using  `XSSFCell` as a formula cell it does not occur.

The answer is that `SXSSFCell` **always** uses a cell value, even if the formula was not evaluated at all. And the worst thing is that it uses the value 0 (zero) if if the formula was not evaluated at all. This is a fundamental misusing of the value 0 in mathematics. The value 0 explicitly does **not** mean that there is not a value or that there is a unknown value. It means that there is the value 0 and nothing else. So the value 0 should **not** be used as the cached formula result of a not evaluated formula. Instead **no** value should be used until the formula is evaluated. Exact as `XSSFCell` does.

So the really correct answer must be that `apache poi` should correct their `SXSSFCell` code.

Workaround until this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CreateExcelSXSSFFormula {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();

  SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Test-S");
  SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

  SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue(124);

  SXSSFFormulaonlyCell formulacell = new SXSSFFormulaonlyCell(row, 1);
  formulacell.setCellFormula("A1+17");

  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellFormula("A1+17");

  formulacell = new SXSSFFormulaonlyCell(row, 3);
  formulacell.setCellFormula("A1+18");

  cell = row.createCell(4);
  cell.setCellFormula("A1+18");

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("test-s.xlsx"));
  wb.close();
  wb.dispose();

 }

 private static class SXSSFFormulaonlyCell extends SXSSFCell {

  SXSSFFormulaonlyCell(SXSSFRow row, int cellidx) throws Exception {
   super(row, CellType.BLANK);
   Field _cells = SXSSFRow.class.getDeclaredField("_cells"); 
   _cells.setAccessible(true);
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //we know the problem and expect runtime error if it possibly occurs
   TreeMap<Integer, SXSSFCell> cells = (TreeMap<Integer, SXSSFCell>)_cells.get(row);
   cells.put(cellidx, this);
  }

  @Override
  public CellType getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum() {
   return CellType.BLANK;
  }

 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Axel Richter; that looks very interesting. Yes, SXSSFRow does not have any protected methods or members, so the only reasonable way of extending it is by reflection. I see that `SXXSFCell` .`getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum()` is deprecated; maybe that means that the POI developers are not currently working on that topic – or that its use is discouraged.

Comment: @Renardo: My provided workaround is **not** a solution but a workaround only. The solution is to change `SXSSFCell`'s code so that it **not** uses the value 0 as cached formula result for not evaluated formulas. But the change management of `apache poi` is weird as well. As of today, the apidocs states `SXSSFCell.getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum()` as deprecated and `SXSSFCell.getCachedFormulaResultType()` returning a `CellType`. But in real version 3.17 **uses** `getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum()` and there `getCachedFormulaResultType()` is returning an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I should have mentioned that I use LibreOffice. I have now found that LibreOffice intentionally does not recalculate formulae from an Excel-created sheet, and it considers POI sheets as Excel-created.

See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/12165/calc-auto-recalc-does-not-work/ .

Changing the LibreOffice settings (Tools – Options – LibreOffice Calc – formula – Recalculation on file load) helps.